# unable to understand the else if statement in scala code below

Tags: scala

I am pretty new to Scala and was going through the docs when I came across this code in the below link
https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/135.html

```
def filter(xs: List[Int], p: Int => Boolean): List[Int] =
    if (xs.isEmpty) xs
    else if (p(xs.head)) xs.head :: filter(xs.tail, p)
    else filter(xs.tail, p)
```

Can anyone please tell me what the else if line does?

Comment: Just to add that, I did a bit of my research before posting this question here. I found that :: operator is used to create a new list. But that still doesn't help me understand the else if statement.

Comment: That web page is ancient — over a decade old. Please go here instead: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html

Comment: @Seth Tisue Thanks Seth!

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter to the filter function `p` is a function that takes `Int` as a parameter and returns `Boolean`.

So, in the `else if`, it is calling the function `p` with `xs.head` which is first element from `xs` which is `Int`. If it returns true, it adds an element at the beginning of a list and returns a list with the added element.

To test this -

You can try two variations of `p` one which returns true when number is even and one which returns true when the number is odd and see what it prints.

```
val output = filter(List(1,2,3,4), (p) => p % 2 != 0);
print(output) // prints `List(1, 3)`

val output = filter(List(1,2,3,4), (p) => p % 2 == 0);
print(output) // prints `List(2, 4)`
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for that. Can you also tell me what this does:  filter(xs.tail, p)

Comment: added an example for more clarity, hope it helps

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my question clear earlier. What I meant to ask here was, in the  filter(xs.tail, p) , does the value of p come from (p(xs.head))   ? So the value of p would be "true" in this case if xs is not an empty list. Did I get it right?

Comment: `p` is the same function `filter` receives the first time, it is just being passed around in the recursive calls. when you say `value of p`, its `output of calling p`

Comment: and when the `output of calling p` is true, it prepends the head of list to the output of recursive call to the filter with the tail of the list and the same function `p`

Comment: Oh ok. So if, xs= List(1,2,3,4), would the else if statement look something like this?
else if (true 1 :: filter(4,true))

Comment: close enough. its like this: `else if (true) 1 :: filter(List(2,3,4), p))`

Comment: p is a function and not value, its called in the if ()

Comment: it depends on the logic of `p` thats why i gave you two examples :)

Comment: Oh ok. I think I see what you mean now! In that case, what would be the final value of the filter expression? It can't just be filter(List(2,3,4), p).

Comment: final value is always a `List` as the function signature says

Comment: Oh. Perfect! Thanks a lot for helping me out RishikeshDhokare! Cheers buddy :)